# Sitecore Content Hub unit test Could not load file or assembly 'Stylelabs.M.Sdk, Version=4.2.4.0'

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

I tried running the sample test script from the Sitecore Content Hub documentation but it's giving me this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Stylelabs.M.Sdk, Version=4.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system
cannot find the file specified.
```

I already installed the pre-requisites and initialized the working folder.
Does anyone know what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to solve the issue.

1. In the `web.config` file, verify that the bindings exist for the above assembly.
2. If the bindings are missing, add them to the `web.config` file,
3. Run the installation again.

Refer to these articles for related errors in Content Hub.

[Content Hub: Setup and Troubleshooting](https://thebitsthatbyte.com/sitecore-connect-for-content-hub-setup-and-troubleshooting/#Could_not_load_file_or_assembly_8216SystemDiagnosticsDiagnosticSource_Source_httpssitecoredevazureedgenetmedia3662E8C142F4401FB9DD6C986FC0BC02ashxdate20220428T160837)

[Content Hub Installation Guide](https://file:///C:/Users/sbhatia/Downloads/Sitecore_Connect_for_Content_Hub_5_0_Installation_Guide-en.pdf)

Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't have web.config file in my folder. I followed these instructions from Sitecore documentation.
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/cloud-dev/integration-tools--write-unit-tests.html

Comment: @Abby After installation you should have references.json. Did you find any reference of this assembly?

Comment: Yes, there's a references.rsp file generated after installation, and it referenced the Stylelabs.M.Sdk

Comment: @Abby Ok can you check if the version of the DLL is the same that is required for your application?

Comment: Yes. I have checked the version of the DLL, it is the same.